# Passing enum value as parameter .net core

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a controller (ResponseResourceController) which Index Action is supposed to receive as parameter int and in the Index action - Parse enum value from Tempdata. Then this action redirects to another action with this two parameters.

```
    public class ResponseResourceController : Controller
    {
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(
            int id)
        {
            var entityType = (EntityType)TempData["EntityType"];
            var exists = await _responseResourceStringUiService.ResponseResourceStringExistsAsync(
                id,
                entityType);
            return RedirectToRoute(!exists ?
                RouteNames.ResponseResourceString_Home_Add :
                RouteNames.ResponseResourceString_Home_Edit,
                new {id, entityType});
        }....
    }

   public class PublicationController : Controller
   {
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var vm = new PublicationViewModel
            {
                ...
            };
           
            TempData["EntityType"] = InboxEntityType.Publication;
            ........
       }
```

My question is - is there more elegant way to achieve this without the enum value beeing in the url after the redirection.
I was thinking for example to create an abstract property of thids Enum Type  in this ResponseResourceController
AND the other controller PublicationController(and othe that are going to do that) to inherit it and override the property with the right enum value and as the ResponseResourceController will have property I will not need the entity type as parameter in the Add and Edit Action.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't just directly call the PublicationController and avoid creating an unnecessary redirect? You can distinguish directly in the frontend if it is a new or an existing record.
If you wanna use this method for creating new records then you should prefer to use a POST request instead of GET.

Answer (score 0):

In short, multiple controllers does not work and url redirection is not necessary.

From the description I think what you really want is displaying the add/edit form base on an ID (with your temp entity type stored in somewhere). If this is what you want then **single controller with multiple views** should be able to handle that.

#### What will happen when you create multiple controllers?

The routing rules in the app has to be **unique**. If you have a `ResponseResourceController` and a `PublicationController` and each of them has the `Index` action, what will be the routes look like?

You probably need to define a route like `/ResponseResource/Index` for `ResponseResourceController.Index()` and a route like `/Publication/Index` for `PublicationController.Index()`. If there is a `EntityType` called `Bob`, you may need to define a route like `/Bob/Index` and create a `BobController`.

**However, if you try to name a unique route for each of the `EntityType`, your route has to contain that piece of information (either in the route or in the query string).** So, creating a dedicated controller for each `EntityType` cannot solve your problem.

#### Multiple views for multiple entity types

If you don't want to include the `EntityType` in the url, you may use `ResponseResourceController.Index(int id)` to get the entity ID **and respond with different views for different `EntityType`**:

```
[Route("/response-resource")]
public class ResponseResourceController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int id)
    {
        var entityType = (EntityType)TempData["EntityType"];
        var exists = await _responseResourceStringUiService.ResponseResourceStringExistsAsync(id, entityType);
        var viewName = exists ? "_AddEntity" : "_EditEntity";
        var vm = new GenericViewModel
        {
            type = entityType,
            /* other fields */
        }
        return View(viewName, vm); // so user may see a different view under different situation
    }
}
```

And for the view model:

```
public class GenericViewModel 
{
    public EntityType type { get; set; }
}
```

You also need to define 2 views: `_AddEntity` and `_EditEntity`. In the above example, `GenericViewModel` contains the `EntityType` so you will know which entity you are handling.

Furthermore, you can even define a dedicated view for each `EntityType` and pass a dedicated view model to that view. e.g. `PublicationViewModel` will be the view model used in `_AddPublication` and `_EditPublication` views.

#### Expected behavior

When user requests for **ResponseResource** with and id, e.g. `/response-resource?id=123`, your application will render the view base on the `id` and the `EntityType`. No url redirection and url won't change.